# Creating objects from constructors with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to Console.Write() arrays from a constructor in Main. I am also trying to override ToString() to Console.Write() an array of ints as a string, but haven't found a clue how to do it.

```
 namespace Z1
 {
 class List
 {


  public List(int b)
  {
    int[] tabb = new int[b];
    Random r1 = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
      tabb [i] =r1.Next(0, 100);
    }
  }

  public List()
  {
    Random r2 = new Random();
    int rInt1=r2.Next(0,10);
    int[] tabc = new int[rInt1];
    Random r3 = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<rInt1;i++){
      tabc [i] = r3.Next(0,100);

    }
  }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      List l1 = new List(10);
      List l2 = new List();
      Console.WriteLine(l1.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(l2.ToString());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried googling "How to override ToString in C#"?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to change are the two arrays. They are local variables and when you exit from the constructor they are simply discarded and you cannot use them anymore. I think you want just one array that could be created with a size specified by your user or with a random size between 1 and 10.

Finally you can override of ToString() in the usual way and return a Join of the array

```
class List
{
    static Random r1 = new Random();
    private int[] tabb;

    public List(int b)
    {
        tabb = new int[b];
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            tabb[i] = r1.Next(0, 100);
    }
    // This constructor calls the first one with a random number between 1 and 10
    public List(): this(r1.Next(1,11))
    { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", tabb);
    }
}
```

Now your Main method could get the expected result.

As a side note, I suppose that this is just a test program so there is not much concern, but in a real program I strongly suggest you to avoid creating class with names that clashes with the classes defined in the framework. It is better to avoid names likes List, Task, Queue etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can't just print the array, you'll have to print each value separately. Try using this instead of just `Console.WriteLine();`. Also make sure at the top of your class you have `using LINQ;`

```
l1.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
l2.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```